# Is it possible to set lint custom settings and ignores for pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Previously when using pylint I have have used custom comment settings to ignore undefined vars when editing in vscode, for example:

```py
# Make pylint think that it knows about additional builtins
data = data  # pylint:disable=invalid-name,used-before-assignment,undefined-variable
DEBUG = DEBUG # pylint:disable=invalid-name,used-before-assignment,undefined-variable
VERBOSE = VERBOSE # pylint:disable=invalid-name,used-before-assignment,undefined-variable
```

Note my application has it's own python based cut down scripting language hence the additional builtins.

I've not been able to find an equivalent for pylance.
Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Jill thanks for the suggestion but I want to selectively pick out variables to exclude from the check.

Comment: I have submitted this proposal and let us look forward to a good solution. Github link: [Is there a setting to turn off specific errors displayed by Pylance](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/929)

Answer (score 7):

You can add the following settings in `settings.json` configuration file:

> ```json
> "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
>     "reportUndefinedVariable": "none"
> }
> ```

Or you can search for `python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides` in the settings, click <kbd>Add Item</kbd> button to select "`reportUndefinedVariable`", "`none`":

[image]

#### Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Following the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/929) that @Jill Cheng linked in the comments, the pylance devs suggest using a `# type: ignore` comment after the line in question. You will lose out on other linting abilities for this line though so apply with caution.

As a side note, if you're using this to quiet the messages due to `"import <module> could not be resolved"` then you should look into correctly configuring your workspace rather than overriding the message. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65786221/import-flask-could-not-be-resolved-from-source-pylance-reportmissingmodulesou) an example answer to help you solve that issue.