# Unable to Import the requests module (Python)

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I was trying out Python for the first time today and I ran into a problem. I want to *import requests*, but it shows an error in the code:

> Error: Import "requests" could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModelSource) [4, 8]

I am using Visual Studio Code.

I've tried `pip install requests` and it looks good, but I'm still getting an error in my code.

When I do `pip install requests`:

(Removed locations except for first)

```
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop\python testing01> pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\me\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Relevant Python code:

```
import random

import requests
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error: Import "requests" could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModelSource) [4, 8] @OlvinRoght

Comment: Related: [Import “flask” could not be resolved from source Pylance (reportMissingModuleSource)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65786221/10824407)

Comment: Okay, I am assuming that you're using VS Code. (If so, please edit your original question to include this information.) Are you sure that you have selected the global interpreter rather than some other virtual environment from a previous session? See this for how to check that: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Comment: Also, check if it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65786221/import-flask-could-not-be-resolved-from-source-pylance-reportmissingmodulesou

Answer (score 1):

First of all, uninstall *request* by the following command:

```
pip uninstall requests
```

Then you have to install it again by the following command:

```
pip install requests
```

Now you have to import *requests* in the following way:

```
import requests
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade pip. Try:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

If your OS is Windows *and* if *this* command doesn't work, try:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then try to install requests. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to :

1. Upgrade pip

```
    pip install --upgrade pip
```

2. Uninstall requests

```
    pip uninstall requests
```

3. Install requests

```
    pip install requests
```

4. Then reboot VsCode

Answer (score 0):

I had to install in the terminal and then it worked.  Would not work when attempting in my IDE, (VS Code).

Comment: Sometimes your IDE runs a different Python environment then the one that your terminal defaults to, you may want to check what Python environment it's running.