# VS Code + Pylance does not find venv-installed modules while venv is activated

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, pylance, python-3.11

I use VS Code Version: 1.74.3 on MacOS 13.2. `python -V` returns `Python 3.11.1`.

I get the following error message: `Import "django.shortcuts" could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModuleScource)`.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the correct `venv` is activated and includes `Django`.

[image]

I also tried or checked:

1. [Import could not be resolved/could not be resolved from source Pylance in VS Code using Python 3.9.2 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68486207/2321643)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65802367/2321643 but
3. the suggested solution with reloading the windows did not help.
4. reinstallation the virtual environment within VSCode and installing Django again
5. re-selecting the venv.
6. deleting all python-specific settings in `user/settings.json` as well as `.vcode/settings.json`.
7. Reinstallation python and associated extensions.

Using Debug I can safely run my Django-application without any import issues. What do I need to do that Pylance does not issues these problems?

Comment: did you activate the venv or did VSC do the activation on opening the terminal

Comment: I start VSC and the venv is immediately activated yet the error still occurs. I update my post with an additional screenshot.

Comment: what does this PROBLEMS screenshot explain about who activates the venv

Comment: Sorry, @rioV8, I did not get your point.

Comment: you add an image of the error message, that has no new information

Comment: What information would you find beneficial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was a bug, fixed and closed.

For reference: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3881

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on where it says "3.11.1 ('.venv': venv)" (near the bottom right).
It should bring up a little dialog sort of thing at the top where you can verify that the Python path is correct.

Check that it is using the correct Python path. It should be something like `venv/bin/python3` or `venv/bin/python` assuming `venv` is situated at the root of youur project.

Comment: It's the right path.