# Pylance shows error when variable type changes

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

How to avoid this VSCode + Pylance static type check error?

```
def process_row(row: dict[str, Any]):
    row = SimpleNamespace(**row)
```

For this, vscode shows red underline for `SimpleNamespace(**row)` with messsage: Expression of type "SimpleNamespace" cannot be assigned to declared type "dict[str, Any]"

Comment: call `row` variable something different than what argument for the function is called.

Comment: Yes. But that increases memory AFAIK. For this particular use case, I think that will be fine but for something big, it may have memory implications.

Comment: single variable assignment will be absolutely irrelevant in terms of memory usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to set lint custom settings and ignores for pylance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64649795/is-it-possible-to-set-lint-custom-settings-and-ignores-for-pylance)

Comment: Why is `row` an argument at all, if you're going to reassign it?

Comment: I didn't know that re-using variables is bad practice in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching and going through `github` issues for `pylance` and `mypy`, it appears that this is legitimate open issue for `pylance`.

`mypy` kind of fixed this. For above function, running `mypy typetest.py` gave 1 error: `Name "row" already defined on line 5` but rnunning with `mypy --allow-redefinition typetest.py` was all green.

You can not yet turn of this in `pylance` it seems but let people know here if anyone point this out. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rahul, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also can I answer my own question.., Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following codes to your `settings.json` in `.vscode` folder to turn off error warning:

```
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportGeneralTypeIssues": "none"
}
```

Comment: I don't want to turn off warning as legit warning are welcome. This is not legit warning. its always good idea to re-use variables.